# Why global temp table doesn't gets dropped even after checking table exists condition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I am running a sql server script where I am checking it global temp table exists, then drop it. However I have observed that lot of time even after table exists, compiler never enters into the drop table scope.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##TuidSubgroupAuthrealm') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE ##TuidSubgroupAuthrealm
END

CREATE TABLE ##TuidSubgroupAuthrealm
( 
    TUID INT NOT NULL, 
    TravelProductId INT NOT NULL, 
    AuthRealmId INT NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (TUID, TravelProductId)
)
```

`select * from ##TuidSubgroupAuthrealm` When querying this, I get the table however script breaks at create table. Any reason and how to fix it?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the code.

Comment: If you are using a global table I'm guessing you have concurrent processes that use them. Maybe you have racing conditions to drop/create it?

Comment: Why are you using a Global temporary table? They're, generally, not a good idea.

Comment: No, I created this table with same name few days back. I know I am the only one running this script and no other connection is using this script except the original creator i.e older connection. Reason for using global temp table is to debug processing of data in parallel from another connection.

Comment: Do you really need a global temporary table, i.e. is that temporary table used in a sessions outside the scope in which it is created? If not, use a local temporary table instead. Also, you should be dropping a temporary table as soon as you don't need it anymore. Reversing it, i.e. dropping it before you need to create it, is not how you should handle these. It signals a problem in your script, as when you enter the script and assume it might exist, i.e. it can be used in another scope, you then proceed to drop it? Do you see where I'm getting at?

Comment: I am using a bcp using xp_cmdshell and for this cmd shell need a table where data can be loaded. So we need global temp table for this. Ideally I expect connection to be closed as soon as script has been executed. However I am not sure if connection has been closed or not. I expect connect to be closed. Scripts we provide are executed by DBA team, so I can't comment on that side.

Answer (score 0):

You should separate the `DROP` and `CREATE` statements in different batches.
If you are using SSMS try placing a `GO` separator between them.

Comment: That's a better coding practice, I am looking for root cause.